# Preciso de bitcoins (ou qualquer outra moeda) rodando numa blockchain?

Tags: criptografia, blockchain

Preciso de bitcoins ou qualquer outra moeda pra ter um aplicativo rodando em uma blockchain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim.

---

A blockchain em si é como um mero banco de dados, *talvez seja o pior banco de dados de todos*.

Porém, um banco de dados não "roda" uma aplicação. Tipicamente é o contrário, uma aplicação consome ela. Isso é exatamente o que ocorre com a maior parte das moedas, como o Bitcoin, mencionado por você.

O Bitcoin apenas registra as transações, essas transações precisam ser "aceitas" por mineradores. Eles são responsáveis, através de uma prova de trabalho, por incluir sua transação na blockchain. A cada transação taxas devem ser pagas.

O valor das taxas depende do tamanho da transação. As transações incluem várias informações, os *inputs* (as transações não-gastas), os *outputs* (o destinatário) e a assinatura (a assinatura criptográfica), etc. Quanto mais informações houverem, mais caro ficará.

Uma maneira de armazenar um conteúdo arbitrário na blockchain é usando o `OP_RETURN`, no Bitcoin ele é limitado é em 60 bytes. Existem moedas que não possuem limite ou limites maiores, ou outros recursos específicos.

Cada moeda possui seu custo e tempo de confirmação, isso também deve ser considerado. Neste mesmo ponto, cada moeda tem sua própria blockchain. Você terá que ter a respectiva moeda, se for usar a blockchain da Dash, terá que ter Dash *(e não Bitcoin)*. Você também deve procurar por moedas "fortes", afinal qualquer blockchain é vulnerável à uma ataque de 51% e se a moeda for "descontinuada", seus dados serão perdidos.

---

Existem outras moedas, como o Ethereum, que permite executar uma aplicação, usando o DApp. Mas, de qualquer forma, ele também não é gratuito. Você terá que pagar o *Gas* para que ele "rode".

---

Você não necessariamente precisa inserir tudo na blockchain, fazer isso criaria várias transações e gastando várias moedas em taxas. Você pode inserir apenas uma hash, originada de uma *hash-tree*. Assim, será capaz de verificar a integridade de vários dados, apenas com uma hash.